# Is it possible to call api when app is installing from app store

Tags: ios, deep-linking

Firstly, I know question is conceptual based rather than coding so apologise for mistakes.

I am working on an app, now there is a scenario that if I received an sms and when I click on sms then two cases happened...

1. If app installed in device, then open specific screen and called api
2. If app not installed then download from app store and during installation call an api from server and manage some response.

The concept may be of deep linking, but I don't know how to manage the scenarios and I know during installation api call is not possible, but is there any way to achieve this...?

Comment: You can access deep link meta data when the app is first launched (this can be easily implemented with services such as branch.io) and based on that, call the needed server API. Do you have to call this API when the app is downloaded?

Comment: No, this will be my 1st experience for deep link.

Answer (score 3):

Use **Deferred deep linking**  with custom parameters using [branch.io](https://branch.io/)

Deferred deep links can route users to content even if the app is not installed when the link is opened. The link will first redirect to the App Store or Play Store to download the app, and then take the user to the specific “deferred” content immediately after first launch.

An example:

Basic workflow: http://blogs.innovationm.com/deferred-deep-linking-in-ios-with-universal-link/

-> User selects domain link on web.

-> Link sets referral ID to cookie.

-> User redirected to app store.

-> On app launch, load referral page in SFSafariViewController.

-> Referral page checks for cookie and if it exists calls a deeplink
   into the app with the referral ID.

[image: How branch deep link work]

https://docs.branch.io/pages/apps/ios/

https://branch.io/what-is-deep-linking/